Noun+なの, when の is the indefinite pronoun?
I've read about how noun+な is only grammatical in usages like 〜なの. However, does this generalize to when の isn't the "explanatory の", but rather serves as an indefinite pronoun? That is to say, can you say Ａなの to mean "the one that's A"?
Or, are you required to reword it, e.g. as Ａであるの or Ａのもの, or even restructure the sentence entirely?
I'm having trouble thinking of relevant examples in English, at least that can't be reworded in a way that avoids the question entirely. Still, here's the kinds of things that I'm thinking about:

Say I'm at a restaurant and offered the choice between a beef taco, a chicken taco, and a fish taco. I might say, "I'll take the chicken one." Could this be translated 鶏肉なのにします｡? Or is it necessary to instead say something like 鶏肉が入っているのにします。or 鶏肉のほうがいいです｡?

If someone's at a fork in the road and asks which street they should take, I might say "Take the left one." Could this be translated 左なのを行って｡? Or would you instead say something like 左の道を行って。or 左のものを行って｡?


(I'm implicitly assuming that Ａのの is always ungrammatical—please correct me if I'm wrong about this!)
EDIT: I think my confusion really arose from the fact that all the material for beginners—at least from what I've seen—drums it into you that you cannot use な with nouns, and then なの is introduced as a special case that breaks the rules. So, I wasn't sure if that applies to の in full generality, or if "な+explanatory の" was specifically fossilized.


That is to say, can you say Ａなの to mean "the one that's A"?

Yes. Just as 安いの means "cheap ones", 安価なの means "cheap ones", too. In this case, の is not a nominalizer but a pronoun meaning "thing(s); one(s)".
Similar examples:

簡単なのは解き終わった。
I've finished solving easy ones.
綺麗なのに3人会った。
I met three beautiful ones/people.
このチームにはまだ学生なのも何人かいる。
This team has some people who are still students.

Although this pattern works, note that it's usually more common to use a little more specific nouns such as もの, 奴, 方 or 人. Also note that this pattern doesn't work with so-called no-adjectives. For example, 緑のの is ungrammatical, and you need to say 緑のやつ or 緑のもの to mean "green ones". While 鶏肉なの(をください) is understandable, it's much better to say 鶏肉のやつ, 鶏肉のほう or 鶏肉のもの.

Oh, I hadn't considered how this would work with の-adjectives—could you not say 緑なの? I guess I'd naïvely assume that の-adjective+な would be the same as noun+な, since they share so many other characteristics....

First, な is the way to connect relative clauses to nouns, and NOT reserved specifically for の. In English, you use the word that to connect nouns to relative clauses, such as the man that likes Western music, but in Japanese, you put the relative clause before　the noun, and, if the clause ends with noun or na-adjective, a な is needed.

The man that likes Western music
洋楽が好き な 人

Since 洋楽が好き happen to end with 好き, which is a na-adjective, you add a な between the relative clause and the noun as a connector. However, this is not needed when the relative clause ends with i-adjective or verb.

The man that likes Western music
洋楽を好む 人
洋楽が好ましい 人

Here, I just replaced 好き with synonyms, but since the part-of-speech changed, な is no longer needed.
Now, the の is, after all, a noun. If the preceding clause ends in noun, or that the clause is so short it only contains one noun/na-adjective, you'd have to use な, otherwise for verbs and i-adjectives, you append the の directly.　The so-called "explanatory の"　is, in essence, the same thing as the "indefinite pronoun　の". The reason they call it that is because by adding this "indefinite pronoun" in the end of a sentence gives a softer, thus more "explanatory", tone of voice. Grammatically they're not meaningfully distinguished.

僕は学生なの。 ⭕️
僕は学生の。 ❌


僕はそこに行ったの。 ⭕️
僕はそこに行ったなの。 ❌

Now let's answer your questions more directly.

Or, are you required to reword it, e.g. as Ａであるの or Ａのもの, or even restructure the sentence entirely?

Ａなの is fine as-is. As explained above, it should be translated to just "Ａ" instead of "The one which is A", although the latter is more accurate to Ａなの's literal meaning. Saying Ａであるの or Ａのもの is not wrong per se, but depending on context, they'd have a stronger emphasis than a simple Ａなの。

Say I'm at a restaurant and offered the choice between a beef taco, a chicken taco, and a fish taco. I might say, "I'll take the chicken one." Could this be translated 鶏肉なのにします｡? Or is it necessary to instead say something like 鶏肉が入っているのにします。or 鶏肉のほうがいいです｡?

鶏肉にします or 鶏肉のほうがいいです are the best ones. 鶏肉が入っているのにします means "the one that contains chicken", not "I choose chicken". The problem with 鶏肉なのにします is that it's too wordy, and thus unnatural. Here is an example where 鶏肉なの is naturally used though.

Q: What's this meat? It's so good! A: Chicken.
Q：これ、なんの肉なの？めっちゃ美味いんだけど！A：鶏肉なの。


If someone's at a fork in the road and asks which street they should take, I might say "Take the left one." Could this be translated 左なのを行って｡? Or would you instead say something like 左の道を行って。or 左のものを行って｡?

左の道を行って is good. 左のものを行って and 左なのを行って are too wordy and unnatural. In fact, saying 左のもの places an emphasis on もの, and translate to "the left thing". Wouldn't you be confused or feel unnatural if you ask for directions(in English) and someone answered "Take the left thing"? I sure would be. Just like English, specifying the object "左の道" or "the left road" is the best way to phrase it.
*Note how I say that they're unnatural, not grammatically wrong. They may be un-idiomatic, sure, or the meaning/emphasis is different from what you really want to say, but grammatically their construct is OK.

(I'm implicitly assuming that Ａのの is always ungrammatical—please correct me if I'm wrong about this!)

Yes this one is actually ungrammatical. In this case we just say Aの。

Q: Which one do I choose? A: Choose the left one!
Q：どっち選べばいいの？A：左のを選べ！


Regarding Ａのの, if A is verb or i-adjective in attributive form, and if you want meaning "something of the person/thing which does/did ...", then you can end up with のの. First の is nominalizer / pronoun, and second の is genitive case particle.

I don't see how “〜な” is needed with nouns at to connect to relative clauses. For nouns and no-adjectives, “〜の” is generally used. Surely one would say “破壊神がビルス様の宇宙” not “〜な宇宙” for instance?

Thanks for the answer! I'm also somewhat confused about the point that Zorf brought up. Also, regarding "鶏肉が入っているのにします means 'the one that contains chicken', not 'I choose chicken'.": That really is the specific nuance that I'm trying to express in English, though, by saying "the chicken one" instead of just "chicken" (if that makes any sense)....

Also, could you elaborate on the very last point (Ａの)? Is that similar to this construction: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/90458/why-is-there-a-%e3%81%ae-in-this-sentence-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%86%e3%81%ae%e3%81%ab%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b? As a beginner, seeing a bare の feels "wrong" somehow—assuming that it is serving as the genitive particle here—and so I'm trying to figure out exactly where my mental model is breaking down.

The OP of that question asked a similar question in the comments, but it doesn't look his questions were ever definitively addressed. Is it the same idea as how you can say e.g. 私の on its own to mean "mine", without explicitly clarifying after のwhat type of thing you're talking about?

@JoshGrosso The question you're referring to doesn't seem too related to yours, and aguijinzo has said in a comment on that question that the の is redundant in his case, which I fully agree. 私の on its own can and does mean "mine". :)

To add to @dvx2718's answer which is correct is that the key to your misunderstanding seems to be not realizing that there are two “〜の”. One is a genitive marker, comparable to “of” in English, the other is an attributive form of “〜だ”, the other being “〜な”. How it works depends on which “〜の” is expressed.
With the attributive form of “〜だ” which may be replaced with “〜である” for a comparable meaning, one indeed uses “〜なの” to attach “〜の”. One can look at this “〜の" as essentially a placeholder for about any noun possible which context suffice. For instance:

“子供なのは私じゃなくてお前だ。” -> “The one who is a child here is you, not I.”, here it can be said to replace “人” in a way.
“子供なのはわかる。” -> “I can see you are a child.”, here it can be seen to  be replaceable with “事実”. Here, the “〜の” unlike in the above sentence does not function as the subject of the relative clause. It's not “the fact which is a child” but simply “The fact that you are a child”
“パンを切るのはナイフだ。” -> “What I cut the bread with is a knife.”, here it essentially stands for “道具”. In theory the sentence could also mean “What cuts the bread is a knife.” The only reason it resolves to this meaning is because knives don't generally cut on their own but are tools used to cut. Similarly “パンを切るのは台所だ。” resolves to “Where I cut the bread is the kitchen.” purely by what makes sense.

In the first two examples however, we can replace “〜な” with “〜である”. However in the two examples of “左” and “肉” we are in a different position, in “鶏肉の料理" and “左の道” the “〜の” takes the genitive function instead. The dish and road aren't chicken or left respectively, but related to it somehow. In that case, as @dvx2718 explains, a simple “左の” as a noun suffices to mean “the left one”. “左なの” is indeed not grammatically incorrect, but it does not so much mean “the left one” as “that which is the left hand side” or whatever.
Finally, while coercing the normally “〜の” attributive form to “〜な” even for things that normally would take “〜の” is mandatory in front of another “〜の”. It also happens, though isn't mandatory, in front of “わけ” “はず” and rarely “ため”, such that “子供なわけがない” occurs alongside “子供のわけがない”

Thanks! I've edited my question slightly to address the first half of your answer (but I don't think you should change your answer or anything, for the sake of future readers). Is there perhaps an extra word at the beginning of the last paragraph (specifically, "while" looks out of place to me)? Finally, I've asked some related followups in the comments to dvx2718's answer—I'd comment them here too but I don't want to end up spamming :-)

According to Samuel Martin as explained in his “A reference grammar of Japanese language” the Japanese particle (の) is the conflation of different particles which stems from different etyma.
He lists the following occurrences of (の):

“of” possessive case marker
Subject case marker in attributive clauses (as alternative to (が))
Pronominal “one,fact,it” . Maybe an historic truncation (もの) “thing”
Attributive variation of the copula (な) in certain adnominalizations

He then lists a fifth instance due to an obligatory reduction to a single の of の の (4+3) “the one which” and of の の (1+3) “the one of/belonging to”
So
1+3: 太郎の車とジョしュのの→
太郎の車とジョしュの
The car of Taro and the one of Josh
4+3
友達で病気ののがジョシュです→
友達で病気のがジョシュです
Among my friends, the one who is ill is Josh.

I disagree with Martin's contention that these different uses indicate different etyma — these senses are all deducible from a single root の, as what appears to be the attributive form of an ancient prehistoric (pre-written-form) copular element also reflected in directional / locative / adverbial particle に and stative / completive aspect suffix ぬ.  If memory serves, Frellesvig describes this in his book A History of the Japanese Language.

@elrkr útlendi . Thanks for the tip. I will look for the book you have mentioned. To be honest, even Martin and other sources point at this ancient root to

See pages 354-367 in Frellesvig's book. Meaning 3 (nominalizer / pronoun) developed as extension of case particle meaning (and not from any もの), seemingly in 17th century. Page 365 mentions research by another linguist Janick Wrona: "As for the emergence of no as a nominalizer, Wrona points out that no emerges as a nominalizer after the increase in the use of no as a complementizer in adnominal clauses, proposing that this use as complementizer in adnominal clauses formed the basis for the generalization of no as a nominalizer."

(Also you can write @ and first letter(s) of somebody's username to see completions. Your comment had typo in @EiríkrÚtlendi, so it would not have generated notification for him. My comment now should ping him...)
